# How can i dispatch an Event, if the mobile device is rotated in Actionscript 3

Tags: actionscript-3, air

I just want an Event to happen, if the Mobile Phone is rotatated and i am searching for a solution for days now. Can anyone help, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can listen to the [`StageOrientationEvent`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/StageOrientationEvent.html) fired by the `Stage` object. Eg. something like this:

```
stage.addEventListener(StageOrientationEvent.ORIENTATION_CHANGE, onOrientationChange);
```

Comment: Kind of? :) You still have to check the events `afterOrientation` property to find out which way it was rotated.. it can be any value from the [StageOrientation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/StageOrientation.html) class. If this answer helped you, feel free to mark it as the accepted answer :)